# Ubuntu video card driver trouble Intel UHD 600

Tags: intel

I have UHD 600 Intel, but it is detected as 605

Why these models do not match?

Comment: What is your real problem? The devices are usually share driver for a family of devices. Please add the output of `lspci | grep -iE "VGA|Video|3D"` , `lsmod | grep drm` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1264244/edit). If you care about full acceleration - run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y vainfo` and share the output of `vainfo` too.